# Trying to delete a single value from array

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a value from a passed array at the selected index. Basically taking the selected index of a list box that displays the arrays and using it to delete an entry. For some reason nothing is deleted and stays the same when I run the program. I am programing in Visual Studio 2010 in C#

```
public double [] redrawArray(double[] ary, int selectedIndex)
{
    double[] redoneArray = new double[ary.GetUpperBound(0)];

    for (int i = selectedIndex; i < ary.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        redoneArray[i] = ary[i + 1];
    }
    //redoneArray[ary.GetUpperBound(0)] = 0;
    return redoneArray;
}
```

Here is the delete button portion of code

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex;
    if (this.lstClients.SelectedIndex <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    //else if ((this.lstClients.SelectedIndex - 2) < arrayIndex)
    else
    {
            selectedIndex = this.lstClients.SelectedIndex - 2;
            this.lstClients.Items.RemoveAt(this.lstClients.SelectedIndex);
            lbSI.Text = (this.lstClients.SelectedIndex - 2).ToString();
            redrawArray(mFirstNameArray, selectedIndex);
            redrawArray(mLastNameArray, selectedIndex);
            redrawArray(mAgeArray, selectedIndex);
            redrawArray(mHeightArray, selectedIndex);
            redrawArray(mStartWeightArray, selectedIndex);
            redrawArray(mGoalWeightArray , selectedIndex);
            redrawArray(mTotalWeeksArray, selectedIndex);
            //arrayIndex += -1;                    
            lstClients.Items.Clear();
            loadListBox();
    }

}
```

And here is my main code that loads it into the list

```
private void loadListBox()
{
    string currentClient;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    string formattedName;
    string strAvgBMI;
    string strLowBMI;
    string strHghBMI;
    double dStartAvgBMI;
    double dStartLowBMI;
    double dStartHghBMI;
    double dEndAvgBMI;
    double dEndLowBMI;
    double dEndHghBMI;


    lstClients.Items.Add("   CLIENT NAME      AGE    HEIGHT(in)   START WEIGHT    START BMI    GOAL WEIGHT    GOAL BMI     WEEKS");
    lstClients.Items.Add("=================  =====  ===========  ==============  ===========  =============  ==========  =========");

    for (int index = 0; index < arrayIndex; index++)
    {
        if (mFirstNameArray[index] == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        lineNumber++;
        formattedName = mFirstNameArray[index];
        formattedName += " ";
        formattedName += mLastNameArray[index];
        mStartBMI[index] = calcBMI(mHeightArray[index], mStartWeightArray[index]);
        mEndBMI[index] = calcBMI(mHeightArray[index], mGoalWeightArray[index]);
        currentClient = index.ToString() + "   ";
        currentClient += formattedName.PadRight(18) + " ";
        currentClient += mAgeArray[index].ToString("##").PadLeft(4) + "      ";
        currentClient += mHeightArray[index].ToString("##.#0").PadRight(4) + "          ";
        currentClient += mStartWeightArray[index].ToString("###.0").PadRight(4) + "         ";
        currentClient += mStartBMI[index].ToString("##.#0").PadRight(4) + "         ";
        currentClient += mGoalWeightArray[index].ToString("###.0").PadRight(4) + "         ";
        currentClient += mEndBMI[index].ToString("###.#0").PadRight(4) + "       ";
        currentClient += mTotalWeeksArray[index].ToString("##").PadRight(4);

        lstClients.Items.Add(currentClient);
    }
    dStartAvgBMI = sumAvg(mStartBMI, arrayIndex);
    dStartHghBMI = maxArray(mStartBMI, arrayIndex);
    dStartLowBMI = minArray(mStartBMI, arrayIndex);
    dEndAvgBMI = sumAvg(mEndBMI, arrayIndex);
    dEndHghBMI = maxArray(mEndBMI, arrayIndex);
    dEndLowBMI = minArray(mEndBMI, arrayIndex);

    strAvgBMI = "";
    strHghBMI = "";
    strLowBMI =  "";
    strAvgBMI = "                                            Average:      " + dStartAvgBMI.ToString("0#.#0") + "                       " + dEndAvgBMI.ToString("0#.#0");
    strHghBMI = "                                            High:         " + dStartHghBMI.ToString("0#.#0") + "                       " + dEndHghBMI.ToString("0#.#0");
    strLowBMI = "                                            Low:          " + dStartLowBMI.ToString("0#.#0") + "                       " + dEndLowBMI.ToString("0#.#0");
    lstClients.Items.Add(strAvgBMI);
    lstClients.Items.Add(strHghBMI);
    lstClients.Items.Add(strLowBMI);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? Additionally, any reason you are using an array over generic list?

Comment: As @Oded said you will probably fare much better using a `List<double>`. Also, I think it would help if you show us how you are adding the array's contents to the `ListBox` since it might also be a data binding issue.

Comment: I am using an array because it is a class assignment and calls for it. I tried using a listbox but it went over my head at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend using a `List<double>` instead, since it has a more graceful and efficient strategy for adding and removing items.

There is a significant problem with your algorithm, because you haven't actually used `selectedIndex` to filter out the 'deleted' item. I think it should look like this

```
public double[] redrawArray(double[] ary, int selectedIndex)
{
    double[] redoneArray = new double[ary.GetUpperBound(0)];
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < selectedIndex; i++)
    {
        redoneArray[i] = ary[i];
    }
    for (; i < redoneArray.Length; i++)
    {
        redoneArray[i] = ary[i + 1];
    }
    return redoneArray;
}
```

Or even better:

```
public double[] redrawArray(double[] ary, int selectedIndex)
{
    double[] redoneArray = new double[ary.GetUpperBound(0)];
    Array.Copy(ary, redoneArray, selectedIndex);
    Array.Copy(ary, selectedIndex + 1, 
               redoneArray, selectedIndex, redoneArray.Length - selectedIndex);
    return redoneArray;
}
```

---

**Update**

The real problem, however, is that you're `redrawArray` method returns a *new* array rather than modifying the existing array. You'd have to use assign the result array back to your variables, like this:

```
mFirstNameArray = redrawArray(mFirstNameArray, selectedIndex);
mLastNameArray = redrawArray(mLastNameArray, selectedIndex);
mAgeArray = redrawArray(mAgeArray, selectedIndex);
mHeightArray = redrawArray(mHeightArray, selectedIndex);
mStartWeightArray = redrawArray(mStartWeightArray, selectedIndex);
mGoalWeightArray = redrawArray(mGoalWeightArray , selectedIndex);
mTotalWeeksArray = redrawArray(mTotalWeeksArray, selectedIndex);
```

Comment: Ohhh +1, I like your second solution much more than mine.

Comment: I've been trying this and it I get the same results, the arrays do not change. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Wilken The the problem is somewhere else. You'll need to post more of your code.

Comment: DOH that makes sense now. I don't have enough reputation to Upvote you. But you are my hero!

Comment: @Wilken If this (or any other) answer has solved your issue, you should accept it. Or if multiple answers solved your issue, you should accept the one which most completely answered your question. Once you get 15 rep you can upvote any answer you felt was well written or useful to you. See also [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You're starting from the `selectedIndex`.. but the new array doesn't contain any of the source array. This makes everything *before* the index `0`. This can be solved with `Array.Copy`.

```
public static double[] redrawArray(double[] ary, int selectedIndex) {
    double[] redoneArray = new double[ary.GetUpperBound(0)];

    Array.Copy(ary, redoneArray, ary.GetUpperBound(0)); // copy the source into the destination minus one..

    for (int i = selectedIndex; i < ary.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
        redoneArray[i] = ary[i + 1];
    }

    return redoneArray;
}
```

Example usage:

```
double[] arr = new double[] {2, 4, 6};

// remove first
arr = redrawArray(arr, 0); // {4, 6}
// remove second
arr = redrawArray(arr, 1); // {2, 6}
// etc..
```

Comment: Tried this as well and it still does not delete anything from the arrays. I declare some basic arrays in form main and have an add function and even the added items stay. I have overloaded the method for strings, int, double to do about 8 arrays. No information in the arrays change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array which you can delete things from, then its best to use something like `List<double>`, which will save you a lot of trouble.

Then to delete at a particular index, just call `.RemoveAt(index)`

If you still want to use Arrays externally, you can 'cheat' by using the `array.ToList()` function to get yourself a list, delete whatever it is you want, and then `.toArray()` it back. Yeah its quite inefficient, but I don't think what you're currently doing is that fast as it is.

Comment: I like the idea but VS2010 doesn't support .ToList()

Comment: @Wilken Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file? That is needed for many of the answers (mine as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
public double[] RedrawArray(double[] ary, int selectedIndex)
{  
    var lst = new List<double>(ary);
    lst.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    return lst.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Linq I guess you can:

```
public double[] RedrawArray(double[] ary, int selectedIndex)
{
  return ary.Where((d, i) => i!=selectedIndex).ToArray();
}
```

or:

```
public void RedrawArray(ref double[] ary, int selectedIndex)
{
  ary = ary.Where((d, i) => i!=selectedIndex).ToArray();
}
```

depending on which syntax is most convenient when calling the method.

Note that in either case the array passed to this method should not be modified by other threads while the method is running. In the `ref` case, if a field or captured variable was passed, that variable must not be re-assigned by other threads.